# Swift : Possible to overload randomVar as? [MyStruct]?

Tags: swift, overloading, operator-keyword

My server returns an array of photo informations in JSON like that :

```
"pics":[{"ID":182,"ID_member":39,"fn":"b69ea6f6c88b58c67a331aa3c5eaff81.jpg"}, ...]
```

I have a struct init function made to handle one photo json raw array (from type [String:Any]) :

```
init?(fromRaw _img:[String:Any]?)
{
    guard
    let img   = _img,
    let id    = img["ID"] as? Int,
    let idm   = img["ID_member"] as? Int,
    let fn    = img["fn"] as? String
    else
    {
        OOTLog.info("Warning : unable to init from photo raw array")
        return nil ;
    }


    self.id = id
    self.idMembre = idm
    self.fileName = fn

}
```

My question is : lets say we have a json from server (of type [[String:Any]], array of n raw photos), is there any way to "overload" `as? [Photo]` with my `init?(fromRaw:)` within Photo struct, so we could just code :

```
guard let arrayPhoto = jsonRaw as? [Photo] else ..
```

Instead of :

```
guard let arrayPhotoRaw = jsonRaw as [[String:Any]] else .. 
let photoArray:[Photo] = []
for p in jsonRaw {
    guard let p = Photo(fromRaw:p) else { continue }
    photoArray.append(p)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let pics: [Pic]
}

struct Pic: Codable {
    let id, idMember: Int
    let fn: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "ID"
        case idMember = "ID_member"
        case fn
    }
}
```

---

```
 let res = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from:data)
 print(res.pics)
```

Comment: the above code will decode the data which should be dictionary as your current json and internally transforms the nested array to the var `pics`

Comment: Ok thanks i got it :) When having this king of tiny struct, is it good practice to let it in the same file ? or every even tiny struct should have its own file ?

Comment: this relates to your design patterns whether MVC or MVVM and many more , sure having it in a separate swift file would be the right way to go